# Dynamically changing the color of a line in knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js

I have a css class that draws a line like this:

```
.divider {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-top-color: #000;
}
```

Now each time I draw this divider, I want to dynamically change the color. I am using the style binding on the div element like this:

```
<div class="divider" data-bind="style: { border-top-color: $data.color }"></div>
```

But somehow the color does not change. And I get this error:

```
knockout.js?body=1:2937 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: style: { border-top-color: $data.color }
Message: Unexpected token -
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use styles that have a hyphen, because it is not a valid JavaScript identifier. [Knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html), section *Note: Applying styles whose names aren’t legal JavaScript variable names* describes what you need to do instead:

> If you want to apply a `font-weight` or `text-decoration` style, or
>   any other style whose name isn’t a legal JavaScript identifier (e.g.,
>   because it contains a hyphen), you must use the JavaScript name for
>   that style. For example,
>
> - Don’t write `{ font-weight: someValue };` do write `{ fontWeight: someValue }`
> - Don’t write `{ text-decoration: someValue };` do write `{ textDecoration: someValue }`
>
> See also: [a longer list of style names and their JavaScript
>   equivalents](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javastyle.html)

So in your case instead of

```
<div class="divider" data-bind="style: { border-top-color: $data.color }"></div>
```

you should use

```
<div class="divider" data-bind="style: { borderTopColor: $data.color }"></div>
```

Comment: That's not 100% accurate - you can still use hyphenated css properties, as long as you wrap them in quotation marks. e.g.  `<div class="divider" data-bind="style: { 'border-top-color': $data.color }"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

As @kasperoo mentions, use single quotes around `border-top-color`.

```
<div class="divider" data-bind="style: { 'border-top-color': $data.color }"></div>
```